# Scaffold-DbContext : how can I generate comments for model classes?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using .NET 5.0.101, Entity Framework Core 5.0.101, Visual Studio 2019, ASP.NET Core Blazor WebAssembly 5.x, Microsoft SQL Server 2019.

In Package Management Console, I run this command:

```
PM> Scaffold-DbContext "Server=DESKTOP-CA6GPT5;Database=sampledb;User Id=sa; Password=SECrEtP@ssword;Trusted_Connection=True;" 
             Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 
             -OutputDir Models -Tables "Unit" -ContextDir Data 
             -Context ApplicationDbContext -force
```

I want model classes that are generated by `Scaffold-DbContext` to have comments, how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not implemented in EF Core 5, but you can use EF Core Power Tools.